# How to Convert ["abc","efg"] array to "["abc","efg"]" (string) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm asked to convert `["abc","efg"]`

**output** should be `"["abc","efg"]"`

How can I do it using javascript?
I have tried searching so much, but couldn't find anything.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Should the output be a string?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `'["abc","efg" ]'`?

Comment: Could you add the code that you tried but didn't work.

Comment: What did you search for? "convert array to string in JavaScript"? (which is almost the exact text of your question) How did you not find anything?  Downvoting for lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stringify the value using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

```js
var valArr = ["abc","efg"];
var valStr = JSON.stringify(valArr);
console.log(valStr);
console.log('The type of valStr is:', typeof(valStr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(["abc","efg"]))
```

Note this will *look* like `"[\"abc\",\"efg\"]"` when expressed as a double-quoted string since the inner quotes must be escaped. The value is `["abc","efg"]` *when printed*, which is a string.

Comment: When I click _Run code snippet_ The output does not look like what you say it will look like.  I understand what you're trying to get at, but the way you expressed it is confusing.  Beginning with the array, one need never express this string with escapes, nor see it visualized as such.  So, informative, but maybe just a bit irrelevant?

Comment: @Wyck It's to head of the inevitable "but it has backslashes!!1!" in it.